# How to extract pd rows by column, and shift left by 2 columns

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a csv, `currentData.csv`, that was generated from running a script:

```
| first | last | isStudent | height_in | weight_lbs | age  | favColor | 
| Jane  | Doe  | 21        | red       | True       | 62   | 146.3    | 
| John  | Doe  | 19        | blue      | False      | 59   | 162.2    |
```

My script added 2 column names in the wrong place, so you can see that `firstName` and `lastName` the values in the rows make sense. But past that they don't. Values in all rows currently under the `isStudent` and `height_in` columns need to be removed and appended at the end of the columnss, and then values in the `weight_lbs` columns and beyond would be shifted left 2 columns, holding the column names where they are.

Here's what the csv, `idealData.csv` should look like:

```
| first | last | isStudent | height_in | weight_lbs | age | favColor | 
| Jane  | Doe  | True      | 62        | 146.3      | 21  | red      |
| John  | Doe  | False     | 59        | 162.2      | 19  | blue     |
```

I was fixing `currentData.csv` in Excel (ran into issue where my dtaset > 1 mil rows) by doing the following:

1) for columns `isStudent` and `height_in` only, copy the cells of all rows except those in first row (since those are column names) and append it after column `favColor`. `currentData.csv` will now look like this:

```
| first | last | isStudent | height_in | weight_lbs | age  | favColor |  
| Jane  | Doe  |           |           | True       | 62   | 146.3    | 21 | red  |
| John  | Doe  |           |           | False      | 59   | 162.2    | 19 | blue |
```

2) Then starting at the `weight_lbs` column, for all rows except the first (one with column names), shift the values in all columns to the left by 2.

I've been trying to do this with pandas, and have this so far but am stuck on how to get all rows except the first one (header row) and how to shift cells left by 2 columns.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("currentData.csv")
df_2_bad_cols = df[['isStudent','height_in']]

#get all rows except first one for df_2_bad_cols
#append at end of favColor col in df
#shift all rows except first to the left by 2 cols starting at weight_lbs col
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, you can't start over and make the DataFrame from scratch.  Starting from your bad result, you don't want to move any of the data elements in the DataFrame, you just want to rename the columns.

Try this:

```
df.columns = ["first", "last", "age", "favColor", "height_in", "weight_lbs"]
```

Afterwards, to get the correct order, run this:

```
df = df[["first", "last", "height_in", "weight_lbs", "age", "favColor"]]
```

Comment: You're correct that I can't start from scratch, I must work with the dataset I have. I must also have the `age` and `favColor` columns at the end. If I rename them the way you suggest, can I move those 2 columns from the middle to the end/right of the df?

Comment: OK, you actually have two separate problems.  You can make the column names match the data that the columns contain by doing what I showed above.  But then you also want to REORDER the columns.  I suggest doing this as a second step: `df = df[["first", "last", "height_in", "weight_lbs", "age", "favColor"]]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
 df['isStudent'],df['height_in'],df['weight_ibs'],df['age'],df['fav_color'] = df['weight_lbs'],df['age'],df['favColor'],df['isStudent'],df['height_in']
```

You basicly just change the values.
For the record there is a pandas method called .shift() but that would bring you only trouble in this particular case

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html